# Objectify does not load from Memchache

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

Im doing this standard procedure on my server, with a "@Cache" - Entity

1. load entity, ObjectifyService.ofy().load().key(...)
2. manipulate the entity
3. save the entity, ObjectifyService.ofy().save().entity(...).now()

But when I look up in my appstat I find that there is never a successful load from the Memcache. Because I see a Get-Request to the Memcache followed by a Get-Request to the Datastore, all the time [see it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPml6.png). Meaning that the Memcache does not contain my entity, as I understand. The method is called every 10th seconds.

This is a similar discussion (without an answer for me) I found so far.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/objectify-appengine/d-yzaNLJL4s

Comment: So my Question is: Why is there no successful "Memcache-Load"

Answer (score 1):

In order to ensure memcache stays consistent with your Cloud Datastore data, Objectify has the following rules:

- On `load()`, first try to read from memcache. If that fails, read from Cloud Datastore and store in memcache.
- On `save()`, invalidate the entity in memcache.

So if you always perform `load()` followed by `save()`, you'll never read the entity from memcache -- each request will always invalid your cache.

Comment: Thank you! I did not knew that. I was confused because of the sentence "Writes will 'write through' the cache to the datastore" in the objectify documentation. I thought that the memcache gets updated by the write statement instead of deleted. Pity!